# To generate Flickr Gallery in my wordpress site which plugin to use

Tags: plugins

recently I've checked some of the plugins that generate album from flickr photos but most of them don't work. Here is my purpose:

I want to display images that are hosted in my flickr account. Suppose, I went to a tour. Now I want to show my readers those photos as a gallery. Not all the photos from the photostream will be included, only those which are seperated by tags or somehow. I hope you've understood my problem.

Now, which plugin to use (it has to be free btw)? I'm almost get tired checking most of the available plugins and finding not working on the latest wordpress. So, I need your help.

If there's no possible way to fetch photos from flickr now, is there any other way to host my photos on different location and then creating gallery in my wordpress site?

Please make sure that it goes fine with the current version of wordpress software.

Comment: Plugin Recommendations are offtopic.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin helps you for you to fulfill your requirements.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/awesome-flickr-gallery-plugin/

Comment: This doesn't work.